# How can I find a missing binary needed under Cygwin?

Tags: installation, cygwin, packages

I am trying to put together a cygwin installation and find that the command`tput` is needed, but I have no idea what package supplies it. How can I find the package I need?

**please note: I found have the answer that I will be posting immediately after this making a "help save the next guy" entry, don't bother answering unless you really, really want to**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin has a [package index and search page](http://cygwin.com/packages). Searching for [bin/tput](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=bin/tput) yields:

```
Found 3 matches for bin/tput

ncurses/ncurses-5.7-16  Utilities for terminal handling
ncurses/ncurses-5.7-18  Utilities for terminal handling
ncursesw/ncursesw-5.7-18    Utilities for terminal handling
```

Comment: I find it's better to search for 'bin/<program_name_without.exe>' because some programs are symbolic links or scripts without the .exe suffix, and prefixing with 'bin/' excludes other files.

Comment: @ak2 - edited to incorporate your suggestion; thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have `tput.exe` installed, you can do

```
$ type tput.exe
tput.exe is /usr/bin/tput.exe
$ cygcheck --find-package /usr/bin/tput.exe
ncurses-5.7-18
```

Comment: isn't `cygcheck --find-package tput` sufficient to answer the question? If so, drop the `type` command and yours becomes the accepted answer (I ask because I do not have a cygwin available to confirm this).

Comment: No, you must specify the full path, but you can omit the `.exe` suffix.

Comment: +1 for the cygcheck, but not having tput.exe was the initial problem